# image2DArray :only first layer work

Tags: opengl, glsl

I attempt to use the image load/store function.I need several images,and if they are indexed ,it's convienient for coding,so I want to use the image2DArray uniform.But it seems that only the first layer of the image2DArray works.In another word, the iimage2DArray perform like an iimage.

the fragment shader(only used by fs):

```
#version 420                                                                                                                                                    
coherent uniform layout(r32i) iimage2DArray sigmal;                                                                       
out vec4 FragColor;                                                                                                                                                 
void main()                                                                       
{                                                                               
    ivec2 coord = ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy);
    int increment=100;
    int v=imageAtomicAdd(sigmal,ivec3(coord,**1**),increment);  //the promlem is that it seems 
                                                            //the coordinate z has no influence
    FragColor =vec4(coord/screenSize,v/1000.0f,1);

}
```

the c++ code:
binding:

```
glGenTextures(1,&image);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,image);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER_ARB,0);
//Allocate the storage.
glTexStorage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, GL_R32I, width, height, layerCount);

glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height, layerCount, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_INT, clearData);     //

glBindImageTexture(0, image, 0, GL_TRUE, 0, GL_READ_WRITE, GL_R32I);

//Always set reasonable texture parameters
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
```

render:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,image);
shader.use();
shader.setUniform("sigmal",0);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
shader.unuse();
glMemoryBarrier(GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT);
int *data=new int[viewport[2]*viewport[3]*layerCount];
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY,image);
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER_ARB,0);
glGetTexImage(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0 , GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_INT,data );
printf("%d %d\n",data[0],data[viewport[2]*viewport[3]]);
```

The printf result is data[0] which I think is the first texel of the first layer increase frame by frame,whereas,data[viewport[2]*viewport[3]] which I think is the first texel of the second layer doesn't change.I think the reasonable result is opposite.

Comment: I'm seeing a lack of [explicit synchronization](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Memory_Model#Incoherent_memory_access) in your code.

Comment: I use "glMemoryBarrier(GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT);" And the data[0] will increase frame by frame,while the data[viewport[2]*viewport[3]] never change.

Comment: First, *where* do you use it? And second, you're not doing any texture fetching, so it wouldn't help anyway.

Comment: I think the data[viewport[2]*viewport[3]] is the first texel of the second layer.Is it right?

Comment: after the     glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);
 shader.unuse();

Comment: OK, edit your question so that all of your synchronization code and other important bits are actually present in your code.

Comment: "First, within a single shader invocation, if you perform an incoherent memory write, it will always be visible to that variable for reading."It should mean if I just use the image in fragment shader,then I can read from the image without explicit synchroniazation.

Comment: "*It should mean if I just use the image in fragment shader,then I can read from the image without explicit synchroniazation.*" How did you get that from that statement? It specifically says "visible **to that variable**" and "**within a single shader invocation**". So unless your read is happening within the shader invocation that *wrote* the value, and through the same image variable, no. You need explicit synchronization.

Comment: "I use "glMemoryBarrier(GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT);" - for the glGetTexImage call, you need GL_TEXTURE_UPDATE_BARRIER_BIT

Comment: Sorry.I misunderstood the meaning of "visible".I try to use  GL_TEXTURE_FETCH_BARRIER_BIT .But it doesn't solve my problem @emsi .My problem seems that the ImageAtomicAdd()  write at a wrong location According to my understanding. Or could you figure me out the relationship between the asynchronous and the unexpected result .

Comment: To @emsi and Nicol. The code is right.The mistake is that I link the wrong fragment shader file which doesn't contain the code above .I'm sorry for taking your time for the naive problem.Thanks for your advice to  the synchronization problem.